# i cant get my data to appear in the correct elements when using promises and dynamically generated HTML

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

the problem that im having is that when using functions that return a promise i cant get them to generate the HTML correctly ang therefor i am unable to place it in the correct location.

the code currently creates all the elements from `createClientElement` but only populates the first one.

the code that calls the promises:

```
function previousOrders(){

    for (let i=0; i< UniqueOrderIdList.length; i++) {

        var orderItemsByIdURL = base_url + orderItemsPath + url_auth + "&order_id=" + UniqueOrderIdList[i];

        var index = i;

        function getSuccess(obj){

            var data = obj.data;

            console.log(data);
                                    
            for (let i=0; i< data.length; i++){
                var Widget_id = data[i].widget_id
                var Number = data[i].number
                var PencePrice = data[i].pence_price
                var price =  parseFloat(PencePrice/100).toFixed(2)
    
                Promise.all([getProdDesc(Widget_id), getClientId(UniqueOrderIdList[index])])
                .then((values) => {
                    createClientElement(values[1], index).then(test => {

                        console.log(`index: ${index}`);
                        console.log(`number: ${Number}`);
                        console.log(`productDsc: ${values[0]}`);
                        console.log(`ID:${values[1]}`);
                        console.log(`price: ${price}`);

                        var template2 =
                        `<div>
                            <p class="orderdsc" id="orderdsc_${i}">${Number+": "}${values[0]}
                                <span class="orderItemid" id="orderItemid_${i}">ID:${values[1]}</span>
                                <span class="orderPrice" id="orderPrice_${i}">£${price}</span>
                            </p>
                        </div>`

                    $(`#pastOrderItems_${index}`).append(template2);
                    },onError)
                    
                },onError);
                    
            }
    
        }

        $.ajax(orderItemsByIdURL, {type: "GET", data: {},success: getSuccess });
        console.log("success");
    }
}
```

the `getProdDesc` funtion:

```
function getProdDesc(widgetId){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var prodDescURL = base_url + widgetsPath + widgetId + url_auth;
        
          function getSuccess(obj){
            
            if (obj.status == "success") {

                console.log("Got Product:", obj.data);
                var data = obj.data;
              
                var description = data[0].description;

                resolve(description);

            } else if (obj.message) {
                reject(new Error(obj.message));
            } else {
                reject(new Error("Invalid request"));
            }
              
          }
  
          $.ajax(prodDescURL, {type: "GET", data: {},success: getSuccess });
      });
    
}
```

the `getClientId` function:

```
function getClientId(orderId){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(()=> {
            var prodDescURL = base_url + ordersPath + orderId + url_auth;

            function getSuccess(obj){
              
              if (obj.status == "success") {

                  console.log("Got Client: ", obj.data);
                  var data = obj.data;
                
                  var clientId = data[0].client_id;
                  
                  resolve(clientId);

              } else if (obj.message) {
                  reject(new Error(obj.message));
              } else {
                  reject(new Error("Invalid request"));
              }
                
            }

            $.ajax(prodDescURL, {type: "GET", data: {},success: getSuccess });
        }, 200)

      });
}
```

the `createClientElement` funtion

```
function createClientElement(client, i){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
        
        var clientURL = base_url + clientPath + client + url_auth

        function getSuccess(obj){

            var data = obj.data;
            var client_name = data[0].name
            var client_address = data[0].address
            var client_phone = data[0].phone
            var client_email = data[0].email


            var template =
            `<div class="clientMain">
                <div id="clients">
                    <p class="client top" id="clientName">Client name: ${client_name}</p>
                    <p class="client" id="clientAddress">Client address: ${client_address}</p>
                    <p class="client" id="clientPhone">Client phone: ${client_phone}</p>
                    <p class="client bottom" id="clientEmail">Client email: ${client_email}</p>
                </div>
                <div class="order" id="pastOrderItems_${i}">
                
                </div>
            </div>
            `
            $("#pastOrdersINPUT").append(template);

            resolve("success");
        }

        $.ajax(clientURL, {type: "GET", data: {},success: getSuccess });
    });
}
```

I know that each function works individually and I've gone a little code blind trying to work this out.

reference for what the final HTML result should look like (variable inputs left in for ease of reference):

```
<div id="pastOrdersINPUT">
<div class="clientMain">
                <div id="clients">
                    <p class="client top" id="clientName">Client name: ${client_name}</p>
                    <p class="client" id="clientAddress">Client address: ${client_address}</p>
                    <p class="client" id="clientPhone">Client phone: ${client_phone}</p>
                    <p class="client bottom" id="clientEmail">Client email: ${client_email}</p>
                </div>
                <div class="order" id="pastOrderItems_${i}">
                <div>
                            <p class="orderdsc" id="orderdsc_${i}">${Number+": "}${values[0]}
                                <span class="orderItemid" id="orderItemid_${i}">ID:${values[1]}</span>
                                <span class="orderPrice" id="orderPrice_${i}">£${price}</span>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Switching to `async/await` will probably make things easier.

Answer (score 0):

The function `getSuccess(obj)` in `previousOrders()` referred to `index`, but by the time those ajax call succeed they would all get the same `index` value because `index` has function scope, not block scope. Try changing `var index = i;` to `let index = i;`

Answer (score 0):

You should really consider using async await to make the code more readable and maintainable.

I have made some changes to make it run using a dummy endpoint, and marked some spots that were important.

Maybe you can try to do the changes in your code to see if it would work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>

    <script>
      function createClientElement(client, i) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          var clientURL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users";

          function getSuccess(data) {
            var client_name = data[0].name;
            var client_address = data[0].address.street;
            var client_phone = data[0].phone;
            var client_email = data[0].website;

            var template = `<div class="clientMain">
                <div id="clients">
                    <p class="client top" id="clientName">Client name: ${client_name}</p>
                    <p class="client" id="clientAddress">Client address: ${client_address}</p>
                    <p class="client" id="clientPhone">Client phone: ${client_phone}</p>
                    <p class="client bottom" id="clientEmail">Client email: ${client_email}</p>
                </div>
                <div class="order" id="pastOrderItems_${i}">
                
                </div>
            </div>
            `;
            $("#pastOrdersINPUT").append(template);

            resolve(i); // RETURNS THE PROPER INDEX <<===== #############################
          }

          $.ajax(clientURL, { type: "GET", data: {}, success: getSuccess });
        });
      }

      function getClientId(orderId) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          setTimeout(() => {
            var prodDescURL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments?postId=1";

            function getSuccess(obj) {
              if (obj) {
                var clientId = obj[0].id;

                resolve(clientId);
              } else if (obj.message) {
                reject(new Error(obj.message));
              } else {
                reject(new Error("Invalid request"));
              }
            }

            $.ajax(prodDescURL, { type: "GET", data: {}, success: getSuccess });
          }, 200);
        });
      }

      function getProdDesc(widgetId) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          var prodDescURL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments?postId=1";

          function getSuccess(obj) {
            if (obj) {
              var description = obj[0].body;

              resolve(description);
            } else if (obj.message) {
              reject(new Error(obj.message));
            } else {
              reject(new Error("Invalid request"));
            }
          }

          $.ajax(prodDescURL, { type: "GET", data: {}, success: getSuccess });
        });
      }

      function previousOrders() {
        for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
          var orderItemsByIdURL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1/comments";

          var index = 0;

          function onError(error) {
            console.log(error);
          }

          function getSuccess(data) {
            for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
              var Widget_id = data[i].id;
              var Number = data[i].id;
              var PencePrice = data[i].id;
              var price = parseFloat(PencePrice / 100).toFixed(2);

              Promise.all([getProdDesc(Widget_id), getClientId(1)]).then((values) => {
                index++; // increase the index <<===== #############################

                createClientElement(values[1], index).then((_index) => { // receives the proper index <<===== #############################
                  var template2 = `<div>
                        <p class="orderdsc" id="orderdsc_${i}">${Number + ": "}${values[0]}
                            <span class="orderItemid" id="orderItemid_${i}">ID:${values[1]}</span>
                            <span class="orderPrice" id="orderPrice_${i}">£${price}</span>
                        </p>
                    </div>`;

                  $(`#pastOrderItems_${_index}`).append(template2); // uses the proper index <<===== #############################
                }, onError);
              }, onError);
            }
          }

          $.ajax(orderItemsByIdURL, { type: "GET", data: {}, success: getSuccess });
          console.log("success");
        }
      }

      previousOrders();
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="pastOrdersINPUT"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```